# H.264 call setup SDP parameters negotiation

Tags: sip, h.264

I am working on a video call application which uses H.264 codec for Video Packets. Session setup is done using good old SIP. As a comfort I am using a UVC webcam that has H.264 encoder inbuilt which works on H.264 baseline profile (which is preferred for webcams if I am not wrong). Also the camera support various resolutions.

My question is "is it possible to negotiate on a particular resolution using say SDP parameters or any other mechanism during call setup"?

I am going through SDP parameters used for H.264 based video call but have not found any parameter that negotiates the resolution?

Can anyone suggest how to negotiate the resolution?

But first is it really possible to negotiate the resolution parameters at all?

If it is not possible then do I need to decode the received frame first and then would I be able to check what is the resolution of the received frame?

Any help is really welcome and is deeply appreciated.

Regards,
gs

Answer (score 1):

- SDP is used for session description, it is not used for session negotioation.
- If you are using SIP then after SDP exchange you can negotiate codec using sip "NEGOTIATE" method.

following links should help you -

http://www.hjp.at/doc/rfc/rfc4317.txt

http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/sip/current/msg27863.html

Comment: Hi Rajneesh, Thanks for the answer. I wrote ambiguously to use SDP for session negotiation. Sorry about that. However, what I wanted to know is is there any parameter which can be used to convey resolutions by end points. I will go through the links you provided and will add more if in case I have any doubt.

Comment: Usually, there's no need for SIP negotiate because 2 parties already agree on the exchanged media (inclusing codec, profile, level etc.) during session establishment using SDP offer/answer model. Offerer sends SDP offer embedded in initial SIP INVITE, answerer returns SDP in 200 OK and that's it.